# how to use redis in cpanel for python (django) module celery for sending email asynchrnously

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, cpanel

I have used celery  for sending email asynchronous task I use Redis in localhost for change password but when I want use it for send email asynchronous task  in server Cpanel it gives error like :-

**CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'rediss://myvcci.com:6379/0?ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE'**

**error= A rediss:// URL must have parameter Ssl_cert_reqs and this must be set to CERT_REQUIRED, CERT_OPTIONAL, or CERT_NONE**

```
in views.py

from home.task import email_send

def email(request):
    a=email_send.delay(email,tokenxyz)
    return render(request,"send_email.html")
```

```
in settings.py

import redis

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'rediss://myvcci.com:6379/0'

CELERY_TIMEZONE="Asia/Kolkata"
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND =  'rediss://myvcci.com:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_EXTENDED = True
```

```
in celery.py

import os
from time import sleep

from celery import Celery
from datetime import timedelta
from celery.schedules import crontab

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'alone.settings')

app = Celery('alone')


app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
app.conf.broker_connection_retry_on_startup = True
```

```
in __init__.py 

from .celery import app as celery_app
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

```
task.py

from django.core.mail import send_mail
from celery import shared_task
from time import sleep

@shared_task
def email_send(email,tokenxyz):
    subject = 'Email verification From KartikShop'
    message = f'Hello\nThanks for visiting our site ,Your verification link is "https://myvcci.com/password/{tokenxyz}" \n\nNote:-this link will be valid for 5 minutes long only after that if you want to change password you have request again for verfication.\n\nWith regards.'
    from_email = 'admin@myvcci.com'  # This should be a verified sender email in your email backend settings
    recipient_list = [f'{email}']  # List of recipient email addre
    send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
```

please any one help me i have spend 2 days in it